# Webpack doesn't compile to es5 when entry path is changed

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I have this structure

```
- dist
---- css
---- js
-------- bundle.js
- gulp
---- gulpfile.js
---- webpack.config.js
- src
---- scss
---- js
-------- index.js
```

My webpack compiles the code corectly only if the **src index.js file** is at the same root as the **webpack.config.js**

This is my **current webpack.config.js** file

```
const path = require("path");
const outputDir = path.resolve(__dirname, "../dist/js");

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/js/index.js"),
    devtool: "inline-source-map",
    output: {
       path: outputDir,
       filename: "bundle.js"
   },
   devtool: 'source-map',
   module: {
       rules: [
           {
               test: /\.js$/,
               exclude: /node_modules/,
               use: ["babel-loader"]
           },
           {
               test: /\.js$/,
               use: ["source-map-loader"],
               enforce: "pre"
           }
       ]
   }
```

};

Comment: if i'm not mistaken then you could do entry:  "../src/js/index.js", without path.resolve

Comment: It generates my bundle.js file. But it doesn't compile in es5. I tried also with entry: { import: '../src/js/index.js' }